# How to generate Crystal Report using inner Join query and fill the data set in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to fetch data from three different tables.

Namely **customer**,**orders** and **invoice**.

This query Runs Absolutely Fine in SQL Query analyzer

```
SELECT invoice.invoiceId, customer.customerName, customer.businessName,customer.mobileNumber,invoice.remaining, invoice.total FROM customer INNER JOIN invoice ON customer.customerId = invoice.customerId INNER JOIN orders ON customer.customerId = orders.customerId  where invoice.remaining > 1 AND customer.clientCode IS NULL and orders.[dateTime] between '15/01/2016' and '17/01/2016';
```

But When I try to Execute this query for my Crystal Report it Returns to many Results multiple times. Please Help :(

Here Is my code of C#

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  public partial class creditCustomers : Form
   {
    ReportDocument cryrpt5 = new ReportDocument();

    public creditCustomers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=markcreations;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT invoice.invoiceId, customer.customerName, customer.businessName,customer.mobileNumber,invoice.remaining, invoice.total FROM customer INNER JOIN invoice ON customer.customerId = invoice.customerId INNER JOIN orders ON customer.customerId = orders.customerId  where invoice.remaining > 1 AND customer.clientCode IS NULL and orders.[dateTime] between '15/01/2016' and '17/01/2016'", con);
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        sda1.Fill(dst, "invoice");
        cryrpt5.Load(@"I:\My First Software\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\CrystalReport5.rpt");
        cryrpt5.SetDataSource(dst);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt5;
    }
  }
}
```